# How do specific the attribute I want to get/return and return one to many relationship in a field?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I have a simple product Pojo with hibernate annotation.

```
Class Product
Product ID
name
title
make
colors (1..*) lazy
```

May I know is there a way to get only productID, name, and colors in a single row text ?

example:

```
name: "Monitor"
colors: "Green; Red; Blue;"
```

Reason: The user requires a listing of 5000 listing and it just requires the Name and list the colors in a field.

Hibernate will require 1 query(top 5000) + 5000 queries(Colors) to get the data. I am hoping to get it in 1 query only.

USING: Hibernate Criteria

ADD ON: I have set criteria.maxResult(5000) and when I Use FetchMOdel.JOIN with (Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); It provides me with less than 5000 complete results, this is because each "color" is return in a row..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the following query, with a join fetch which will thus load the colors with the products:

```
select distinct product from Product product 
left join fetch product.colors color 
where ...
```

HQL is well described in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins):

> A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be
>   initialized along with their parent objects using a single select.
>   This is particularly useful in the case of a collection. It
>   effectively overrides the outer join and lazy declarations of the
>   mapping file for associations and collections.

Doing it with criteria is similar (only more tedious: do that only if the where clause is really dynamic):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Product.class, "product");
c.setFetchMode("product.colors", FetchMode.JOIN);
c.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
c.add(...);
```

And here's the relevant part of [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-dynamicfetching):

> You can specify association fetching semantics at runtime using
>   setFetchMode()

You have already asked many Hibernate questions here. Why don't you read the documentation?

EDIT:

From the comments, it appears that you know how to do what you want, but that you have a problem applying a max number of results.

The simplest solution to this problem is to execute a first query, limited to 5000, loading only the IDs of the products. Then execute a second query, not limited, loading the products, with their colors, having an ID in the set of IDs retrieved by the first query:

```
select product.id from Product product where ...

select distinct product from Product product 
left join fetch product.colors color 
where product.id in (:productIds)
```

Beware that some databases (Oracle, for example) limit the number of elements you can put in an `IN` clause (1000 elements max with Oracle). So you might have to partition the set of 5000 IDs into sets of 1000 elements, and execute a query for each of this partition.

Comment: I forgotten I need it using hibernate criteria

Comment: See my edited answer. And read the documentation. That's how you learn.

Comment: Thanks actually I did use  FetchMode.JOIN before but the user wants 5000 records return.. but I get less than 5000 records because I have set "transform" the result.. which just make things worst.

Comment: I don't understand. Post your code, with sample data. Explain what you want it to return, and what it returns instead.

Comment: sadly I can't I work in a stupid cave and can only surf net when I reach home... seriously need to quit this job.

Comment: I have set criteria.maxResult(5000) and when I Use FetchMOdel.JOIN with (Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); It provides me with less than 5000 complete results, this is because each "color" is return in a row..

Comment: See my edited answer. Couldn't you have asked this question directly, rather than hiding the real problem you had and make us discover it afterwards?

Comment: Sorry JB Nizet. I can't remember all the details when I reach home. Once again many thanks. Yes there is a limit of 1000.

Comment: May I know is there a way to get only productID, name, and colors in a single row text ? -> What about this problem, the only way I can think of is create another product class with only the productID, name and colors in it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your database?
You can define a `colorsText` in your entity annotated with a `@Formula('...')` annotation. But you shall write a query which returns a single String for each row.

In most databases there is some kind of `concatenate` aggregate function, just find your database's function.

Comment: Oracle DB, but will it be faster?